# Could we have a way to split questions?

Tags: feature-request, questions

Some users have a tendency to ask a number of questions, sometimes not even very closely related, in a single "question" on Stack Overflow. This makes answers more difficult -- as each answer may be "right" and "wrong" at the same time, it causes incomplete answers as people will often overlook that more than one question was made, and makes them less searchable because the titles are ambiguous and non-specific, reflecting the fact that more than one thing was asked.

I'd like to be able to, somehow, split the question in two, and, if needed, repeat that recursively until every distinct question has its own question/topic. The author of the original question would be preserved.

Comment: Or, just advise them via comment that they should do this themselves...

Comment: I think if this *needs* to be done, the original question should be closed and the OP should post one question at a time.

Answer (score 8):

Not that this is a democracy, but I would vote "no" if this were running in next year's election.

The problems, as I see it:

1. Those with edit rights are basically able to do this anyway which means that this would be high cost for comparably no gain.
2. This isn't exactly a trivial issue — I have difficulty even conceiving of an intuitive UI for this, let alone an elegant one. Cost benefit, once again, suggests that this is a bad idea.
3. This is something which is far more subjective than even edits. When should a user edit, when should he split? What about appropriate sub-questions? And, of course, certain [nautical questions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus) arise.
4. This has the potential to be annoyingly difficult for both the OP and for the moderators — instead of the post being one place, it is in n places where n is the number of original questions.
5. In such questions, often context for a sub-question or secondary question is found in another question. This means that there will either be a lot of duplicate information, or a lot of questions which have been ineffectively pruned.
6. Which question would be the parent/how would they be linked (once again, intuitively and elegantly)?

The best solution is vote to close and comment as to why.